# Scala collection of classes with Implicit Ordering

Tags: scala, collections, implicit

I would like to create an Array (or List, ArrayBuffer, etc) which can only contain instance of classes with defined implicit Ordering (e.g. Int, Long, Double).

Something like this:

```
val ab = new ArrayBuffer[???]()
ab += 7
ab += 8.9
ab += 8L
```

I don't want to compare these values with each other.

Comment: Is it true that you actually want to put into single collection objects of different incomparable types as long as for each type there is some `Ordering[T]`? For example, there is an ordering for tuple if each component has ordering. So is it OK to add tuple `(1.0, "some string")` to your `ab` given that it is fundamentally incomparable with other values you listed? How would you use such `ab` later? What type you expect to get when you get the value out of the `ab` by some index?

Comment: I will have an array of such `ab`-s and I want to compare for example the first value of all - it's granted that all the first elements have the same type.

Comment: You might want to look into using a `HList`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the type class constraint as shown below

```
def createList[T: Ordering](values: T*) = values.toList
```

`T: Ordering` implies only type which has `Ordering` instance in scope are allowed to be passed as arguments to the function.

```
scala> def createList[T: Ordering](values: T*) = values.toList
createList: [T](values: T*)(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[T])List[T]

scala> case class Cat()
defined class Cat

scala> createList(1, 2, 3)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> createList(Cat())
<console>:15: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Cat.
       createList(Cat())
             ^
```

Integer ordering is available in scope but cat ordering is not available in scope. So you cannot pass `Cat` values until you provide instance of `Ordering[Cat]`

Now lets provide some fake ordering and see if compiler accepts `Cat` as argument

```
scala> implicit val orderingCat: Ordering[Cat] = (a: Cat, b: Cat) => ???
orderingCat: Ordering[Cat] = $anonfun$1@6be766d1

scala> createList(Cat())
res4: List[Cat] = List(Cat())
```

It works.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work if you want to store a `Cat` and a `Double` in the same array.
For example when you want to store an `Int` and a `String` in the same array, it will look up the implicit ordering for their common supertype, which is `Any` for which there is no implicit Ordering defined.

Comment: @DánielBerecz Provide the ordering if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a list of objects of different types and still be able to statically check things about the objects in that list at compile time, you would have to use something like a `HList` from [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). Here is an example of how you could have two heterogeneous lists and still check at compile time that each i<sup>th</sup> element of both lists can be compared with each other.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{LiftAll, Zip, Mapper}

object lt extends Poly1 { 
  implicit def instance[A] = at[(Ordering[A], A, A)] { 
    case (ord, a, b) => ord.lt(a, b)
  } 
}

def areLessThan[L <: HList, O <: HList, OLL <: HList](a: L, b: L)(
  implicit 
  ord: LiftAll.Aux[Ordering, L, O], 
  zip: Zip.Aux[O :: L :: L :: HNil, OLL], 
  map: Mapper[lt.type, OLL]
) = zip(ord.instances :: a :: b :: HNil).map(lt)
```

Using it:

```
scala> val a = 1 :: "b" :: Option(4L) :: HNil
a: Int :: String :: Option[Long] :: shapeless.HNil = 1 :: b :: Some(4) :: HNil

scala> val b = 2 :: "a" :: Option(7L) :: HNil
b: Int :: String :: Option[Long] :: shapeless.HNil = 2 :: a :: Some(7) :: HNil

scala> areLessThan(a, b)
res10: Boolean :: Boolean :: Boolean :: shapeless.HNil = true :: false :: true :: HNil
```